# How can I get a closely approximation of the golden spiral?

Tags: asymptote

```
size(400);

pair A=(0,0),C=(1,1),M=(A+(C.x,A.y))/2;
filldraw(box(A,C),pink);
draw(M--C,blue);

real tmax=degrees(C-M)-degrees((C.x,A.y)-M);
pair K=rotate(-tmax,M)*C;
draw(C--(K.x,C.y)--(K.x,A.y)--(C.x,A.y));

draw((A.x,C.y)--(K.x,A.y),blue);
draw((K.x,C.y)--(C.x,A.y),blue);
pair Inter=intersectionpoint((A.x,C.y)--(K.x,A.y),(K.x,C.y)--(C.x,A.y));
path rightangle=Inter--Inter+0.1*unit((A.x,C.y)-Inter)--
                               rotate(-90,Inter+0.1*unit((A.x,C.y)-Inter))*Inter--
                               Inter+0.1*unit((C.x,A.y)-Inter)--cycle;
filldraw(rightangle,magenta,blue);

real m=1/(1+abs((K.x,C.y)-C)); 
// write(m); // 0.618033988749895

int N=100;
pair Z[];
for (int i=0; i<=N;++i)
{
 real t= i/10;
  Z.push(rotate(-t*90,Inter)*(Inter+m^t*(A-Inter)));
}
draw(operator .. (... Z),red);
shipout(bbox(2mm,invisible));
```

[image]

[image]
Question:

From above code, is it a closely approximates a golden spiral? (If not,how can I improve it?)

Additional:

I have looked at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_spiral and tried to check approximation as follow:

```
import graph;
picture Pic;
size(Pic,400);

pair A=(0,0),C=(1,1),M=(A+(C.x,A.y))/2;
real tmax=degrees(C-M)-degrees((C.x,A.y)-M);
pair K=rotate(-tmax,M)*C;

pair Inter=intersectionpoint((A.x,C.y)--(K.x,A.y),(K.x,C.y)--(C.x,A.y));
real m=1/(1+abs((K.x,C.y)-C)); 
// write(m); // 0.618033988749895

int N=100;
pair Z[];
for (int i=0; i<=N;++i)
{
 real t= i/10;
  Z.push(rotate(-t*90,Inter)*(Inter+m^t*(A-Inter)));
}
draw(Pic,shift(A-Inter)*(operator .. (... Z)),red);
add(Pic.fit());

picture pic;
size(pic,400);
pair A=(0,0),C=(1,1),M=(A+(C.x,A.y))/2;
real tmax=degrees(C-M)-degrees((C.x,A.y)-M);
pair K=rotate(-tmax,M)*C;
pair Inter=intersectionpoint((A.x,C.y)--(K.x,A.y),(K.x,C.y)--(C.x,A.y));
real a=1, k=Tan(17.03239);
real f(real t) {return a*exp(k*t);}

path g=polargraph(f,0,6pi,500,operator ..);
draw(pic,rotate(180)*g,lightblue+white);
add(pic.fit());

shipout(bbox(2mm,invisible));
```

[image]

However, I don't know which is true or my code is fail? Please help!

Besides, the plot is incomplete.

Comment: You could precompute the samples, either externally or using \pgfmathparseFPU.

Comment: Are you sure that it is not correct ? There is a difference between approximating golden spiral with Fibonnaci numbers and squares decomposition (quarter of circles) and the real equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two objects are the same and the golden spiral. I think it is more a mathematical question than an asymptote one. It is a variable problem and the way (in direction to the center or not) to describe the spiral.

To compare it is better to have the same scaling, so avoid `pic.fit`. Then you have to do some computations.

In the first case (up to the translation and a rotation), the equation is in polar coordinates `phi=-pi t/2` `r=m^t`. If `u=-pi/2 t` we have in the variable `u`, the polar coordinates `phi=u`, `r=m^(-2 u /pi)`. It follows that in `u`, `r=exp(-u *2log(m)/pi)` and `-2log(m)/pi=tan(17.03239)`.
Up to a scaling, a rotation and the choice of the interval both examples are the same : golden spiral.
You can observe on the following example

```
import graph;
size(400);
pair A=(0,0),C=(1,1),M=(A+(C.x,A.y))/2;
real tmax=degrees(C-M)-degrees((C.x,A.y)-M);
pair K=rotate(-tmax,M)*C;

pair Inter=intersectionpoint((A.x,C.y)--(K.x,A.y),(K.x,C.y)--(C.x,A.y));
real m=1/(1+abs((K.x,C.y)-C));
// write(m); // 0.618033988749895

int N=100;
pair Z[];
for (int i=0; i<=N;++i)
{
 real t= i/10;
  Z.push(rotate(-t*90,Inter)*(Inter+m^t*(A-Inter)));
}
draw(shift(A-Inter)*(operator .. (... Z)),red);
pair A=(0,0),C=(1,1),M=(A+(C.x,A.y))/2;
real tmax=degrees(C-M)-degrees((C.x,A.y)-M);
pair K=rotate(-tmax,M)*C;
real a=abs(Inter), k=Tan(17.03239);
k=log(1+m)/(pi/2);
real f(real t) {return a*exp(k*(t-pi-angle(Inter)));}
path g=polargraph(f,-6pi+angle(Inter),angle(Inter)+pi,500,operator ..);
draw(rotate(0)*g,lightblue+white);

shipout(bbox(2mm,invisible));
```

and the picture

[image]

An interesting picture should be the approximation by quarter circles, Fibonacci sequences.

Comment: `I think it is more a mathematical question than an asymptote one.` Yes, it is right. :-)

Comment: And since it is not possible to have LaTeX formula with MathJax, the message is not easy to read...

Comment: @Chishimotoji nice animation. Is it yours ? As in your picture, the spiral goes "outside" the square, as your very first question. It is the normal behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to Matlab (or Octave, which is the same thing but free) you can define parametric functions such as

[image]

[image]

Picking values a and b will change the shape of the spiral, (see wikipedia for how to choose the correct values)

Now, all you would need is to turn the matlab plot into tikz code, which you can do through a package called matlab2tikz: https://github.com/matlab2tikz/matlab2tikz

Comment: Asymptote can already do this (and doesn't need to go through tikz to put the result in a tex document).

Comment: What is Asymptote? Heard of Geogebra but haven't heard of Asymptote.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asymptote

Comment: I see. Asymptote seems too low-level for my taste. As a college professor, my time is too valuable to spend on learning another language syntax. I would rather prefer a high-level language (such as Matlab), get the tikz output for the figure and use that output for my original .tex document. This only takes minutes, but may not be the most elegant solution to the problem at hand.

Comment: That's entirely reasonable. Asymptote is the best tool TeX-friendly tool for complex 3d diagrams, and is similar to TikZ for complex 2d diagrams (with advantages and disadvantages to each tool). I use asymptote for other things like graphing functions for the same reason you use matlab for TeX figures: familiarity.